# HardFault cortex, how do i debug it

Tags: error-handling, embedded, runtime-error, freertos

I'm using a cortex m4 with freertos and i receive the following error

```
Err: -110595: Hardfault occurred!
```

I have no idea what to check.
The meaning is CRIT_ERR_HARD_FAULT but how do i trace it back?

Comment: Not exactly but maybe related https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/293772/finding-the-source-of-a-hard-fault-using-extended-hardfault-handler

Comment: start with the arm documentation and work backward from there.

Answer (score 1):

It's always tricky and there is no common checklist what should be checked to give you 100% chance for quick success here.

Anyway checking several registers' values should give you enough information to proceed. To do it, you have to know what's the procedure of entering an exception - especially what's happening with core registers and the stack: http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0553a/Babefdjc.html

If you can use online debugging, put a breakpoint in hard fault handler and check the following:

- **stacked PC** - as written in the article above, on exception entry ARM core automatically pushes registers r0,r1,r2,r3,sp,lr,pc and psr on stack. Look it up to check where the program was before execution
- **current LR** - to verify if you came from Thread mode (normal program execution) or another interrupt compare current LR with the table in the article
- **ISR_NUMBER** in **IPSR** being part of current **PSR** - to verify whether in fact hard fault exception occurred or your hard fault handler is used as a sink for all types of faults
- **CFSR** and other fault related registers in **SCB** - it should give you more information what's exactly caused the problem. Since SCB is a peripheral block, it's not visible in most IDEs by default. Install peripheral plugin or simply access addresses via memory inspection window  http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0553a/Cihcfefj.html

If you're unable to do online debugging, you'll need a feature which will dump these registers somehow.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Are your **HardFault** handlers strongly defined? If you have the ability to connect a debugger and the fault is reproducible you can set a breakpoint in your fault handler and check the stack trace for possible areas of interest.

Alternatively, [this guide](https://blog.feabhas.com/2013/02/developing-a-generic-hard-fault-handler-for-arm-cortex-m3cortex-m4/) provides a highly portable and useful method of diagnosing hard faults and gathering information post fault for the ARM processor.